# Can you help me understand this PDF derivation please?

Tags: probability, derivatives, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Can you help me understand [this pdf derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ06b.png) please? The part that I don't understand is when we differentiate $F_x(\frac{y - b} {a})$ by $dy$. Where does $\frac{1}{|a|}$ came from? How this differentiation happens?

Comment: It's a normal chain rule. You have a function
$$
g(y) = \frac{y-b}{a}
$$
and you want to differentiate $f(g(y))$, so the result is of course $g'(y)\cdot f'(g(y))$. In this case, it's easy to see that $g'(y) = \frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: @MattiP. there's an evident typo in your result: $g'(y)\cdot f(g(y))$

Comment: Thanks @Matti P. I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How this differentiation happens?

when you calculate the derivative of an integral function (that is your CDF) you get

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{a(x)}f(t)dt=a'(x)f(a(x))$$

the absolute value is related to the fact that if $a(x)$ is increasing or decreasing the result does not change

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now.